# Linear functional on the set of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $S$  is non-empty set, set
$$l^\infty(S)=\{f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: \|f\|_\infty =:\sup_{x\in S} |f(x)|<\infty\}.$$
Suppose that $\psi:l^\infty(S)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  is a bounded linear functional i.e.
$$\psi(\alpha f+g)=\alpha\psi( f)+\psi(g),\qquad (f,g\in l^\infty(S), \alpha\in\mathbb{R})$$
and 
$$\huge\sup_{f\in l^\infty(S),\|f\|_\infty\leq1}|\psi(f)|<\infty\qquad $$
Prove that for any $g\in l^\infty(S)$ with $g\geq0$,
$$\sup\{|\psi(f)|: 0\leq f\leq g\}=|\psi(g)|$$

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework question posted verbatim.

Comment: It is not homework! I need it to prove it but I don't know how.I only know it was solved in lattice theory.I need it's proof without using lattice theory.

Answer (score 2):

Check this book:

Real analysis by Charalambos D.Aliprantis, OwenBurkinshaw

Comment: I said it's described by lattice theory, but not exactly this